# system.js downloads browser.js which is 2mega bytes

Tags: systemjs, jspm, babeljs

I'm trying to convert require.js project to system.js based one.

On network tab, I see browser.js which is 2MB.
I found it is actually `npm/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.js`

And I think this is to convert (transpile) javascript file somehow in development.

How do I convert beforehand (probably when bundling) so that I don't have to download 2MB browser.js

I am working with jspm 0.17 and I can go back to 0.16 if I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bundle for a module with all its dependencies using systemjs builder

```
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

var builder = new Builder;

builder.loadConfig('config.js').then(function() {

    builder.bundle('module.js', 'module.bundle.js', {minify: false});

});
```

Then load resulting bundle with a `<script>` tag before the first time the module is imported.

You also can make a bundle for all source files like this

```
builder.bundle('src/*.js', 'bundle.js')
```